# Given an array of characters, how can i take multiple digits from this array and assign it to an int value?

Tags: c, arrays, character, strtol

So say i have a char array as such

```
char *array = "hello my name is steven 123*3";
```

and i want to extract the `123` from this expression and put it in an `int`.

I know i can do something like

```
int firstnum = array[15] - '0';
```

(assuming the 1 is the 15th character in the array), and this will give me `firstnum = 1`.

But I would like to be able to get the whole `123` number into a single integer, and im not quite sure how to do this.

Any help is appreciated

Edit: I just found out about something called strtol, but am unsure of how to use it.

I'm thinking 
long numberwanted = strtol(array[15], *p, 10);
But how do i let it know when to stop? Or does it stop once you get to a non-int or non-long? and what is *p?

Comment: `array[15]` is 's'. 15 is wrong position.  `strtol(array[15], *p, 10);` : `array[15]` is `char`, not `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sscanf`.

```
  int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
  char ch = 0;
  char *array = "hello my name is steven 123*3";
  sscanf(array, "%*[^0-9] %d %c %d", &n1, &ch, &n2);
```

This assumes the prefix string will never contain a digit.
If it could contain a digit, you could read it from the back something like this (which assumes the data consists of: a prefix string, one or more digits, one character, one or more digits.

```
  int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
  char ch = 0;

  char *array = "hello my name is steven 123*3";
  size_t i = strlen(array);

  while (--i >= 0 && isdigit(array[i]))
    ;
  sscanf(array+i+1, "%d", &n2);

  ch = array[i];

  while (--i >= 0 && isdigit(array[i]))
    ;
  sscanf(array+i+1, "%d", &n1);
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about this, where exactly is my number stored? I would like to be able to use calculations on the number after, would strtol or sscanf be better for this?

Comment: In either of the above snippets, the first number at the end of the string is in `n1`, the second number is in `n2`. They are assumed to be separated by a single char, which is read and stored in `ch`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *array = "hello my name is steven 123*3";
    int num;
    char *p;//p in strtol : Pointer of position where a character that can not be interpreted appeared. point to '*' after execution.
    num = strtol(array + strcspn(array, "0123456789"), &p, 10);

    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```